# How do I offload task from EC2 to worker via SQS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Elastic bean EC2 with Worker setup (I use this for periodic tasks). From what I understand, the periodic tasks get queued in SQS & are read by the worker and executed as a `http://localhost` HTTP Post to the url we set in the `cron.yaml`

```
 - name: "db-backup"
   url: "/cron/db-backup"
   schedule: "30 21 * * *"
```

How do we achieve this using the AWS SDK? All I can see is just the `QueueUrl` and `MessageBody`. How do I specify the URL path i.e. `/cron/db-backup`

```
$client->sendMessage(array(
   'QueueUrl'    => $queueUrl,
   'MessageBody' => 'Hello World!',
));
```

Where should I specify the path `/cron/db-backup`? Or have I got the concept wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was partly correct. You cannot set the HTTP path for individual messages you post to the queue but you can & do set a common path for all the messages to be delivered from where you would implementing a dispatch logic for the code flow.

You set this when you are configuring the Worker tier & can be changed anytime from the Worker configuration section.

[image: Worker configuration]

If you set the MIME type as **application/json** you get the payload from **file_get_contents('php://input')** & if **x-www-form-urlencoded** it is going to **be $_POST**

As simple as it may sound, I was completely lost considering that I can use multiple http paths (urls) when working as a periodic task. I hope this helps others as well.